# Load and unload GeoJSON from Cesium Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, cesiumjs

I have a Cesiumjs display, and I have a checkbox (class `.checkbox`) that I would like to control the display of an item on the map. :

```
        var loadedGeometries = {};

        // We want to load/unload geometries when clicking on the checkboxes
        $('.checkbox').on('click', function (event) {
            var geometryID = id; // some unique database ID for the object to be displayed
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                // it's checked, load it onto the map
                $.get('/geometry/' + geometryID, function (data) {
                    var myDataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(data['points'], {
                        markerSize: 24,
                        markerColor: Cesium.Color.RED,
                        markerSymbol: 't'
                    }); // data['points'] is GeoJSON
                    // Add it to the viewer
                    viewer.dataSources.add(myDataSource);
                    // Remember the data source by ID so we can delete later
                    loadedGeometries[geometryID] = myDataSource;
                }, 'json');
                // SUCCESS! THIS PART WORKS!!
            } else {
                // unchecked, unload it from the map
                viewer.dataSources.remove(loadedGeometries[geometryID], true);
                delete loadedGeometries[geometryID];
                // FAILURE: OBJECT STILL ON THE MAP?!
            }
        });
```

The geometry loads up and gets displayed as I would expect, but when I uncheck the box, the data stays on the map. I am unclear on whether the `remove` function on the `dataSource` is doing what I am expecting it to do. Is this the correct way to remove a `DataSource` from the display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root problem here is that `Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load` is returning a promise, not a real dataSource.  This means that you're attempting to `.remove` the promise from the list of dataSources, and that doesn't work.  Interestingly, adding the promise to the list of dataSources *does* work, it just gets added asynchronously.  Anyway try this:

```
Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(data['points'], {
    markerSize: 24,
    markerColor: Cesium.Color.RED,
    markerSymbol: 't'
}).then(function(myDataSource) {
    // Add it to the viewer
    viewer.dataSources.add(myDataSource);
    // Remember the data source by ID so we can delete later
    loadedGeometries[geometryID] = myDataSource;
});
```

One other comment I'll make, check out the [`dataSource.show`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GeoJsonDataSource.html?classFilter=datasource#show) flag.  If you think the user will toggle a source off and back on, you might not want to unload and reload it from scratch.  You can just set `show` to false while it's toggled off, and it will come back on much more quickly.  It will continue to consume memory of course, but this isn't a big deal unless it's half a gigabyte of data or more.  It won't tax the CPU or GPU needlessly when show is false.

Comment: Thanks, nailed it! I agree about the loading/unloading from scratch. At this point, I'm just trying to get some basic functionality. Thanks again!